# Arduino + Codeblocks C++

Tags: programming, c++, c

I'm writing the code for my Arduino board using Code::Blocks editor. When I create a new project, there is **AVR Project** and **Arduino Project** under Projects category. Which one do I select?

Comment: @chrisl - This looks like an answer. Please make it an answer. Comments on questions are for clarifying the question. To "answer" like this make the SE software think no-one has answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select, what you want. If you want to build an Arduino Project, you should choose "Arduino Project". If you don't want to use the Arduino Framework, you can choose "AVR Project".

Comment: how do I set the path to `arduino.h` and other headers?

Comment: Under project build options, Arduino UNO (which is the version I have) I can see my path is set to `$(ARDUINO_DIR)\libraries` but isnt compiling